# What is the scope and evaluation of this if

Tags: c++

When cleaning up some code that I have found online, I came across with this weird c++ line:

```cpp
if (int i = 1) std::cout << i;
```

With LLVM it compiled fine and the console output is `1`, but how does the scope is handled in here, shouldn't the `i` variable be only accessible inside the conditional (inside the parenthesis)? And how is that possible to be evaluated to true, isn't an assignment a void operation and with no value, so 0/false? What is going on with this line?

Comment: Also: assignment isn't void, it returns the value

Comment: More precisely, assignment operator returns a (reference to) left hand side, so the return value here is `i`.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson assignment of fundamental types and sensibly defined classes returns the value. You can have `void Foo::operator=(...)` if you want